# Convertir String a decimales android studio

Tags: java, android, string, conversión-de-tipos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estoy desarrollando una app en android studio, ya esta algo avanzada la app ya solo se estan afinando cosas, como por ejemplo me enviar por medio de un webservices en asmx el cual lo estoy consumiendo con SOAP, me enviar un metodo que se llama CXCPSaldoDocumento el cual con un filtro me arroja todos los clientes, el cual yo tomo los datos los convierto en objetos para despues mostrarlos en un listview personaliazado, pero el problema es que al momento de yo querer darle formato a los numeros para que me acepte decimales no hace los cambios, segun yo es por que los tengo en string y tengo que convertirlos en decimal u otro formato, necesito de su ayuda.... les dejo mis codigos..

metodo llamar cliente webservices

```
public static ArrayList<Cliente> Clientes() {

    // Create request
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://oncontrol.no-ip.net:9020/","CXCPSaldoDocumento");
    request.addProperty("Documento", "35");
    request.addProperty("Cliente", "0");
    request.addProperty("Proveedor", "0");
    request.addProperty("Moneda", "0");
    request.addProperty("Filtro", "E");
    request.addProperty("FiltroAdicional", " ");
    // Property which holds input parameters

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.implicitTypes=false;
    // Set output SOAP object
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    // Create HTTP call object
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL,7000);

    ArrayList<Cliente> ClienteArray = new ArrayList<Cliente>();

    //ArrayAdapter<String>  arrayadapter;
    try {
        androidHttpTransport.debug=true;
        // Invoke web service
        androidHttpTransport.call("http://oncontrol.no-ip.net:9020/CXCPSaldoDocumento", envelope);
        String ss=androidHttpTransport.responseDump;
        SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();

        SoapObject obj1 = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

        SoapObject obj2 =(SoapObject) obj1.getProperty(1);

        SoapObject obj3 =(SoapObject) obj2.getProperty(0);

        for(int i=0; i<obj3.getPropertyCount(); i++)
        {

            SoapObject obj4 =(SoapObject) obj3.getProperty(i);
            String Cliente = obj4.getProperty("Cliente").toString();
            String ClienteDescripcion = obj4.getProperty("ClienteDescripcion").toString();
            String Saldo = obj4.getProperty("Saldo").toString();
            String SaldoVencido = obj4.getProperty("SaldoVencido").toString();
            Cliente newCliente = new Cliente(ClienteDescripcion, SaldoVencido, Saldo);
            ClienteArray.add(newCliente);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Assign Error Status true in static variable 'errored'
        //menu.errored = true;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Return booleam to calling object
    //return loginStatus;

    return ClienteArray;
}
```

Código arrayadapter personalizado:

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Cliente> {

  public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Cliente> ArrayClientes) {
      super(context, 0, ArrayClientes);
  }

  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

      Cliente O_Cliente = getItem(position);

      // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
      if (convertView == null) {
          convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_detalle, parent, false);
      }

      //Obteniendo instancias de los text views
      TextView nombre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nombrecli);
      TextView saldo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.saldo);
      TextView saldov = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.saldov);

      nombre.setText(O_Cliente.getClienteDescripcion());
      saldo.setText(O_Cliente.getCliente());
      saldov.setText(O_Cliente.getSaldo());

      //Devolver al ListView la fila creada
      return convertView;

  }
}
```

Comment: Hugo, los valores que agregas a tus TextView, saldo y saldov que obtienes del objeto son incorrectos, revisa mi respuesta. Saludos!

Comment: OK Hugo, por ejemplo el valor 674080.66000 que formato deseas puedes agregar un ejemplo?

Comment: si por ejempl necesitaria que se mostrara asi 674.080.6600

Comment: te agregue otra imagen de como es que necesito que se visualizen mis saldos, tomando como ejemplo el que tu me pusiste 674080.66000

Comment: ya pude convertirlo... ahora solo tengo problema para convertir la fecha... la tengo en un string y quiero ponerla en formato fecha

Comment: Que te parece si lo agregas en una nueva pregunta, pon el formato que tienes y a cual deseas convertirlo :) , saludos!

Comment: ya pude, gracias, abrire otro tema

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suponiendo que los valores de `String` de las variables `Saldo` y `SaldoVencido` tienen los siguientes valores:

```
Saldo = "12.324";
SaldoVencido = "52.4355";
```

Puedes realizar una conversión a `Double` a partir de los valores `String`:

```
 Double dSaldo =  Double.valueOf(Saldo);
 Double dSaldoVencido =  Double.valueOf(SaldoVencido);
```

obteniendo los valores:

```
12.324
52.4355
```

En el caso de tu ejemplo, veo que en el Adapter agregas los valores a tus `TextView`, `saldo` y `saldov`, los valores no necesitarían ser cambiados, me parece que  el problema es que los valores que introduces son incorrectos, debe ser algo como:

```
... 
saldo.setText(O_Cliente.getSaldo()); //Saldo
saldov.setText(O_Cliente.getSaldoVencido()); //SaldoVencido
...
```

Comment: ¡`BigDecimal` por favor!

Comment: Elenasys, gracias ya corregi lo de los datos, mira en mi campo de saldov tengo estos datos 673891.5800 pero yo necesito darle el formato correcto de decimales

Comment: le adjunte una imagen de como es que se muestra mi saldo vencido y el saldo

Answer (score 0):

Para esto tipo de caso es recomendable usar DecimalFormat

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.000");
decimalFormat.format(Float.parseFloat("300.3230002000")) // resultado 300.323
```

Puede controlar la cantidad de decimales usando en este caso tengo 3:

```
decimalFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);
```